# Can some one tell me what this means - bundler cannot load required file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, pry

I have this gem I have been using in development and when I deployed my app with Capistrano I made sure to pass in the bundle install arguments as part of the documentation. I watched the app get deployed and the gems be installed and when I ssh'd into my server and logged in as the deployment user, I then went to `appName/current/` and rand `bundle exec promiscuous subscribe` on my development machine this tells me that its replicating ten threads and starts listening for data.

on production though I get this:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require': cannot load such file -- pry (LoadError)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
    from /home/railsapps/aisiswriter/releases/20140707205243/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/railsapps/aisiswriter/releases/20140707205243/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
    from /home/railsapps/aisiswriter/releases/20140707205243/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/railsapps/aisiswriter/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/promiscuous-9bda9a49ac13/lib/promiscuous/cli.rb:207:in `require'
    from /home/railsapps/aisiswriter/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/promiscuous-9bda9a49ac13/lib/promiscuous/cli.rb:207:in `load_app'
    from /home/railsapps/aisiswriter/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/promiscuous-9bda9a49ac13/lib/promiscuous/cli.rb:216:in `boot'
    from /home/railsapps/aisiswriter/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/promiscuous-9bda9a49ac13/gemfiles/bin/promiscuous:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/railsapps/aisiswriter/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/promiscuous:23:in `load'
    from /home/railsapps/aisiswriter/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/promiscuous:23:in `<main>'
```

Now what I cannot tell is if this is a bundler issue, a pry (?) issue or a promiscuous issue. either way **whats going on?** this doesn't happen on development ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely `pry` is only bundled in development mode.

Check your Gemfile.

Comment: yes thats correct, I dont have pry any where else in my code .... so.....what am I missing here.